# Extract carrier out of phone number using libphonenumber

Tags: c#, parsing, phone-number, libphonenumber, carrier

I am using libphonenumber from Google and I want to know what is the correct way to get the carrier prefix from a German mobile number. When I'm using the online demo of libphone number there is a property called "PhoneNumberToCarrierMapper" which in my opinion already maps "0176" and "01577" to the correct carrier:

https://libphonenumber.appspot.com/phonenumberparser?number=%2B4915776510000
http://libphonenumber.appspot.com/phonenumberparser?number=%2B4917665100000

So I think there must be a way to extract the information out of the provided "+49**1577**6510000" "+49**176**65100000"input. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Given, that you can take your number with you, when changing to another carrier, you cannot really identify the carrier by the phone number.
It is just a best guess.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's not the information I want to know. I want to get the number of the carrier. So related to my question I'd like to extract (0)1577 and (0)176 of the provided phone number.

Comment: Ah, it is more, how to get the area code out of a number. I don't think, that that is possible. But you could extract it from the international format?

Comment: I guess there's already a list in the lib having the information about 4 (e.g. 0162) or 5 (01577) digits carrier numbers but I don't know where to find it. At the moment I'm doing a very basic check. I assume that the mobile number after international prefix and carrier prefix always has to be 7 digits. (0)1577-6510000. But I think it's only correct in 95% of the cases :(